# Como marcar campos checkbox dinamicamente com PHP?

Tags: php, array, get

Estou enviando bairros por **$_GET** através de um formulário e gostaria de marcá-los dinamicamente na atualização da tela fazendo assim um sistema de persistência dos resultados buscados.

```
<fieldset class="normal">
    <input type="checkbox" name="bairros[]" value="BELEM NOVO" id="BELEM NOVO">
    <label for="BELEM NOVO">Belém Novo</label>  
    <input type="checkbox" name="bairros[]" value="BOM FIM" id="BOM FIM">
    <label for="BOM FIM">Bom Fim</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bairros[]" value="SANTA CLARA" id="SANTA CLARA">
    <label for="SANTA CLARA">Santa Clara</label>
</fieldset>
```

Incluo o arquivo `bairros.php` logo após o ***body*** com um ***require*** e capturo todos os bairros que foram marcados no formulário com **$_GET** no retorno da página.

```
# Persistencia dos bairros
$inbairros = $_GET["bairros"];
if(array_key_exists("bairros", $_GET)){     
    foreach($inbairros as $baitem => $bavalue) {
        // select bairros       
    }   
}
```

Se eu fizer `echo $bavalue` dentro do `foreach`, logicamente ele me retorna todos os bairros que foram selecionados no formulário. O `value` do input contém o mesmo conteúdo.

***Pergunta***: Como selecionar dinamicamente os bairros retornados e colocar `checked` em todos eles sem precisar tratar um por um?

Comment: Isso é  num formulário de pesquisa e queres manter esses bairros chekados, conforme a escolha na hora da pesquisa?

Comment: Marcos, esse arquivos bairros.php inclue seu formulário? Ele precisa ser gerado dinamicamente ou tens que usar Javascript.

Comment: Jorge é um formulário de pesquisa e quero manter os campos checkados após o submit do mesmo (persistência dos campos).

Comment: Gmsantos, o `bairro.php` contém simplesmente o código foreach adicionado logo após o `body` que vê se house submit do array especifico e pega os dados.

Answer (score 1):

Rapaz... Que pergunta confusa...

Primeiro, isso aqui:

```
$inbairros = $_GET["bairros"];
if(array_key_exists("bairros", $_GET)){     
    foreach($inbairros as $baitem => $bavalue) {
        // select bairros       
    }   
}
```

Deveria ser, pelo menos:

```
$bairros = ( array_key_exists( 'bairros', $_GET ) ? $_GET['bairros'] : array() );

foreach( $bairros as $bairro ) {

    // Faz alguma coisa
}
```

Mas isso ainda não resolve seu problema. Para resolver deveríamos saber como que esse foreach se relaciona com o HTML propriamente dito.

Normalmente é feito algo assim:

```
// Apenas um exemplo, isso viria do banco

$bairros = array( 'bairro1', 'bairro2', 'bairro3', 'bairro4', 'bairro5' );

foreach( $bairros as $bairro ) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="bairros[]" value="' . $bairro . '" id="' . $bairro . '">';
    echo '<label for="' . $bairro . '">' . $bairro . '</label> ';
}
```

E para persistir os *checkboxes* selecionados, algo assim:

```
// Apenas um exemplo, isso viria do banco

$bairros = array( 'bairro1', 'bairro2', 'bairro3', 'bairro4', 'bairro5' );

// Apenas um exemplo, isso seria o $_GET

$bairrosSelecionados = array( 'bairro3', 'bairro4' );

foreach( $bairros as $bairro ) {

    $checked = ( in_array( $bairro, $bairrosSelecionados ) ? ' checked="checked" ' : ' ' );

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="bairros[]"' . $checked . 'value="' . $bairro . '" id="' . $bairro . '">';
    echo '<label for="' . $bairro . '">' . $bairro . '</label> ';
}
```

Leia, entenda e adapte as suas necessidades. ;)